# Subquery in wikidata

Tags: wikidata

I would like to get a list of all the current ministers in Germany.
Those are `CLAIM[39:248352]`.
This gives me all ministers that have ever been there though. I would like to limit it on the current ones though.

So I figured I could go for `NOCLAIM[582]` (no enddate).
How can I apply this to the minister data and not the person himself though?

```
CLAIM[39:248352] AND NOCLAIM[582]
```

Would return all objects that claim to be ministers and have no enddate but I want all objects that claim to be ministers and the minister property has no enddate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do this. You can use curly braces to further filter on your qualifiers. So the query to get all people that are `Bundesminister` and where the `Bundesminister` has a start but no end time is:

```
CLAIM[39:248352]{CLAIM[580] AND NOCLAIM[582]}
```

[demo link](https://wdq.wmflabs.org/wdq/?q=CLAIM%5B39:248352%5D%7BCLAIM%20%5B580%5D%20AND%20NOCLAIM%5B582%5D%7D)

I found out by reading: http://magnusmanske.de/wordpress/?p=178

And specifically by the [example query](http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/autolist.html?q=claim%5B166%3A746756%5D%7BBETWEEN%5B585%2C1853%2C1853-13%5D%7D) for the winner of the Royal Medal in 1853.